# Benchmarking a pure C++ function

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, benchmarking

How do I prevent GCC/Clang from inlining and optimizing out multiple invocations of a pure function?

I am trying to benchmark code of this form

```
int __attribute__ ((noinline)) my_loop(int const* array, int len) {
   // Use array to compute result.
 }
```

My benchmark code looks something like this:

```
int main() {
  const int number = 2048;
   // My own aligned_malloc implementation.
  int* input = (int*)aligned_malloc(sizeof(int) * number, 32);
  // Fill the array with some random numbers.
  make_random(input, number);
  const int num_runs = 10000000;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_runs; i++) {
     const int result = my_loop(input, number); // Call pure function.
  }
  // Since the program exits I don't free input.
}
```

As expected Clang seems to be able to turn this into a no-op at O2 (perhaps even at O1).

A few things I tried to actually benchmark my implementation are:

- Accumulate the intermediate results in an integer and print the results at the end:

  ```
  const int num_runs = 10000000;
  uint64_t total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_runs; i++) {
    total += my_loop(input, number); // Call pure function.
  }
  printf("Total is %llu\n", total);
  ```

  Sadly this doesn't seem to work. Clang at least is smart enough to realize that this is a pure function and transforms the benchmark to something like this:

  ```
  int result = my_loop();
  uint64_t total = num_runs * result;
  printf("Total is %llu\n", total);
  ```
- Set an atomic variable using release semantics at the end of every loop iteration:

  ```
  const int num_runs = 10000000;
  std::atomic<uint64_t> result_atomic(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_runs; i++) {
    int result = my_loop(input, number); // Call pure function.
    // Tried std::memory_order_release too.
    result_atomic.store(result, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  }
  printf("Result is %llu\n", result_atomic.load());
  ```

  My hope was that since atomics introduce a `happens-before` relationship, Clang would be forced to execute my code. But sadly it still did the optimization above and sets the value of the atomic to `num_runs * result` in one shot instead of running `num_runs` iterations of the function.
- Set a volatile int at the end of every loop along with summing the total.

  ```
  const int num_runs = 10000000;
  uint64_t total = 0;
  volatile int trigger = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_runs; i++) {
    total += my_loop(input, number); // Call pure function.
    trigger = 1;
  }
  // If I take this printf out, Clang optimizes the code away again.
  printf("Total is %llu\n", total);
  ```

  This seems to do the trick and my benchmarks seem to work. This is not ideal for a number of reasons.
- Per my understanding of the C++11 memory model `volatile set operations` do not establish a `happens before` relationship so I can't be sure that some compiler will not decide to do the same `num_runs * result_of_1_run` optimization .
- Also this method seems undesirable since now I have an overhead (however tiny) of setting a volatile int on every run of my loop.

Is there a canonical way of preventing Clang/GCC from optimizing this result away. Maybe with a pragma or something? Bonus points if this ideal method works across compilers.

Comment: Keep the function in a different translation unit (source file) to prevent the compiler from realizing that it is a pure function. The compiler cannot optimize across functions if it only knows its prototype.

Comment: @EOF Unless LTO is enabled, so make sure it is not.

Comment: I am sometimes using a macro for inserting stuff in the assembly. # define GCC_SPLIT_BLOCK(str)  __asm__( "//\n\t// " str "\n\t//\n" ); I am not sure, may be this will do the trick

Comment: Yeah LTO would defeat that but it is easy to disable that for a benchmark I suppose.

Comment: @JensMunk That seems to do the trick at least on Clang.

Comment: @Rajiv I use the same trick for speeding up functions, separating loads, calculations and branches. Sometimes the compiler tries to interleave stuff ending in less optimal code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert instruction directly into the assembly. I sometimes uses a macro for splitting up the assembly, e.g. separating loads from calculations and branching.

```
#define GCC_SPLIT_BLOCK(str)  __asm__( "//\n\t// " str "\n\t//\n" );
```

Then in the source you insert

GCC_SPLIT_BLOCK("Keep this please")

before and after your functions

Comment: I can confirm that this works on my version of Clang at least without resorting to separate translation units.

Comment: Doesn't this require an assembler that uses `//` to start a comment line?

Comment: The exact expression above does, but you can do the same using both Intel and AT&T syntax and using compiler intrinsics if you are using Microsoft and 64-bit.